# Translating sentence but how do I deal with conjugation - if it's plural in English, is it plural in Latin?

Tags: grammar-choice, english-to-latin-translation, conjugation

I want to translate "Fear is a crossroads" but I'm confused because in English, "crossroads" is plural, but uses the singular article "a". So would my sentence be "Timor est compitum" or "Timor sunt compita"?

Is nominative even the right form of these words to use in this sentence?

If you have other translations, I'm interested to know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, "crossroads" has an *-s* on the end, but isn't plural—that's why it takes a singular article, and singular verbs ("**a** crossroads **is** a place where two roads meet").

In Latin, it's the same: a single crossing of roads is a *compitum*, and multiple crossings in different places are *compita*.

Apart from that, your translation is good: nominative is to some extent a "default" case you use when no other case applies, and all your word choices are fine (though I'd personally use *metus* for "fear").